# React native admob SDK version error (20.0.0+)

Tags: react-native, admob

I was trying to release an update for my app built with React Native (**version 0.71.3**). Currently, I'm using react-native-admob version **"^2.0.0-beta.6"**. However, I've been informed that this version is deprecated. I'm facing issues with updating it because the line in the build.gradle file specifying the AdMob dependency is deprecated and should be updated to a version greater than 20.00+.

The line in question is:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
```

When I attempt to update it to a newer version, such as:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0"
```

my app crashes. How can I resolve this error?

My usecase is

```
"react-native": "0.71.3", //packages
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",

import {
  AdMobBanner, 
} from 'react-native-admob';

const Footer = () => (
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', width: '100%'}}>
    <AdMobBanner
      adSize="fullBanner"
      style={{width: '100%'}}
      adUnitID="ca-app-pub-6xxxxx4xx/7xxxxxx9"
      onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
    />
  </View>
);
```

I can share more, i really need help, i cant find a way out, is there some new package ?

Comment: i reaally need help, suggest me something

Comment: Moving from `16.0.0` to `20.0.0` is quite a leap, that's 4 breaking changes which means you'll probably need to change some of your configuration to make it work. You'll need to share the error you're seeing when your application crashes, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I think i have mentioned it, theres no runtime error , when i open the app it just crashes,  @admob-next ' s latest verison which i use

Comment: Yes, but you can look at device logs using Android Studio and find out the stack trace causing it